# Effective way to count all categories total number of one table in one query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, count

E.g: **data table** with these records:

```
data_id    data    category
1          hello   1
2          world   1
3          john    1
4          kevien  2
5          apple   2
6          bannana 3
7          desk    4
```

And how can I count the categories total number in one query in MySQL!?

**[UPDATE]**

**How about count total number in special categories.Such as only category 1 and 3??**

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Just add a `"WHERE category IN (1, 3)"` -- before the `GROUP BY` -- to the answers you already got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to the question in the comment, include the `where` clause to restrict it:

```
SELECT category, count(*) from table
       where category in (1, 3)
       group by category
```

Comment: How about count total number in special categories.Such as only category 1 and 3??

Answer (score 2):

```
select category, count(*) 
from theTable 
group by category
```